# Python: Cleanest way to write tuples as rows of a DictWriter?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, tuples, ordereddictionary

Given:

```
with open('results.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['Name', 'Address', '#Reviews']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerow(row)
```

And a list of tuples, each containing a name, address, and #reviews e.g.

```
[('Name2', 'Main St', 2), ('Name2', 'The Hill', 7), ('Name1', 'The Square', 14)]
```

I'm trying to write each tuple as a row in the csv using `writer.writerow()`. I could create a dict for each tuple, thus:

```
In [95]: for tup in z:
   ....:     row = {"Name": tup[0], "Address": tup[1], "#Reviews": tup[2]}
   ....:     print row
```

But (i) it's convoluted and more importantly (ii) the order gets lost in the dict creation, and the order will not match that of `fieldnames`.

I could use an `OrderedDict()`, but again that seems a little convoluted.

What's a neater/shorter way of achieving this?

Comment: where is row coming from?

Comment: sorry, *row* will be represent the dict that I'm looking to create from each tuple/fieldNames combo

Comment: yes but what does it look like, you don't  need DictWriter if you have an iterable of iterables already

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Yes good point Padraic. It's a case of the old 'When the only tool you have is a hammer, you begin to see every problem as a nail." In this case, the only tool I had was DictWriter, and I hadn't before used the more basic variant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your data isn't formatted as a `dict`, why are you using `DictWriter`? Just use a normal `csv.writer`:

```
with open('results.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['Name', 'Address', '#Reviews']
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerow(fieldnames)
    writer.writerows(z) # z is a list of all rows to write
```

Simpler, faster, and much less code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
data = [('Name2', 'Main St', 2), ('Name2', 'The Hill', 7), ('Name1', 'The Square', 14)]
for entry in data:
    row = dict(zip(fieldnames, entry))
    print(row)
```

This will create the appropriate dictionaries that can be passed to `csv.DictWriter`:

```
>>> fieldnames = ['Name', 'Address', '#Reviews']
>>> for entry in data:
...     row = dict(zip(fieldnames, entry))
...     print(row)
...
{'Name': 'Name2', '#Reviews': 2, 'Address': 'Main St'}
{'Name': 'Name2', '#Reviews': 7, 'Address': 'The Hill'}
{'Name': 'Name1', '#Reviews': 14, 'Address': 'The Square'}
```

Comment: I had though of zip, but when I passed the zipped data to *dict()*, the order of the resulting dict does match the order of fieldnames